# Is there a script I can use to search for duplicates between two spreadsheets and append data from the row in one sheet to the other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am preparing an inventory for my employer and would like some help finding a script that can make this a lot easier. I have two spreadsheets, one has all of the part numbers and item descriptions for the items I physically counted in the inventory, and the other is a database from the parts distributor. The boss just told me I need to put the prices on the items in the store inventory, and the prices are listed on the distributors sheet. What I would like to do is get a script to compare the two sheets, and when it finds a matching part number, append the price from the distributor database to the store inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to compare part numbers and get prices from products that are inside **2 tabs in same spreadsheet**. This **can be modified** to use 2 different spreadsheets. It's best to create a test spreadsheet with some data and test before applying on real data.

Copy the code, open script editor in spreadsheet, paste, save. Insert sheet and respective column names accordingly as mentioned in code. A, B etc are not column names. 'Price', 'Part Number' etc are example column names. From menu, click **Run function > Run > onOpen**. It'll ask for auth, give. Reload spreadsheet. It should have a **Custom Menu** item in the menu bar. Click **Get Prices** to execute script.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Get Prices', 'getPrices')
      .addToUi();
}

function getPrices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inv = ss.getSheetByName('inventory sheet name here');
  var dist = ss.getSheetByName('distributor sheet name here');

  var invv = inv.getDataRange().getValues();
  var distv = dist.getDataRange().getValues();

  var inv_price_col = invv[0].indexOf('put inventory sheet price column name here');
  var dist_price_col = distv[0].indexOf('put distributor sheet price column name here');
  var inv_part_col = invv[0].indexOf('put inventory sheet part number column name here');
  var dist_part_col = distv[0].indexOf('put distributor sheet part number column name here');

  var ds = {};
  for (var i = 0, max = distv.length; i < max; i++) {
    ds[distv[i][dist_part_col]] = distv[i][dist_price_col];
  }
  for (var i = 0, max = invv.length; i < max; i++) {
    invv[i][inv_price_col] = ds[invv[i][inv_part_col]] || '';
  }

  inv.getDataRange().setValues(invv);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @ra89fi i tried running this script and when I click Get Prices to execute script, I get an error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null"

Comment: disregard that, I got the script working. Big thanks!